# Jenkins WAR File not deploying on Tomcat - Missing Home Directory?

Tags: java, tomcat, jenkins, tomcat7

So I downloaded the latest Jenkins WAR file from the Jenkins CI website (http://jenkins-ci.org/), and now I'm attempting to deploy it.  However, after I upload the WAR and try and start it via the Tomcat manager GUI, it loads for ~5 minutes and then fails with the following message at the top of the Tomcat manager GUI.

`FAIL - Application at context path /jenkins could not be started`

Upon looking at the logs in `/var/log/tomcat7`, I find this:

```
SEVERE: Failed to initialize Jenkins
hudson.util.NoHomeDir
    at hudson.WebAppMain.contextInitialized(WebAppMain.java:129)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4973)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5467)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1073)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

If it truly is an issue of not having a home directory, how could I resolve this when I'm just simply trying to deploy the WAR?

Any ideas as to how I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

```
#Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.
#Tomcat 7.
#OpenJDK 7.
#(copie jenkins.war from your local to the server <user> directory)
#go to home/<user>
cp ~
#Copie jenkins.war in /var/lib/tomcat7/
cp jenkins.war /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps

sudo chown -R tomcat7:tomcat7 /var/lib/tomcat7/
sudo chown -R tomcat7:tomcat7 /etc/tomcat7/
sudo chown -R tomcat7:tomcat7 /usr/share/tomcat7

sudo service tomcat7 restart
```

And it's ok

Answer (score -1):

You've read the manual, right?
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins

Comment: Yes, I have completed those instructions for Ubuntu and get that exact error.

Comment: "/etc/default/jenkins will capture configuration parameters for the launch like e.g JENKINS_HOME"